# Не работает nth-child()

Tags: css

Не работает **nth-child()** по идее должно быть три разных фона трем блокам,
но у меня везде одинаковой фон =(

```css
.block{
width:200px;
border:1px solid black;
height:150px;
margin:20px;
display:inline-block;
}
.text{
color:red;
font-size:20px;
position:absolute;
}
.Background-img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-size: cover;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}

.Background-img:nth-child(1) {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/68rFc89/1560329641-2.jpg');
}

.Background-img:nth-child(2) {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/wJFNhpN/multfilm-lyagushka-32117.jpg');
}

.Background-img:nth-child(3) {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5jMv9vd/detail-2b7c4f333c37580ee03adaa3bc47c4da.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class ="block">
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>
<p class ="text"> 1 </p>
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>
</div>

<div class ="block">
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>
<p class ="text"> 2 </p>
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>
</div>

<div class ="block">
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>
<p class ="text"> 3 </p>
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Всё работает, во всех трёх случаях ваш `Background-img` является **третьим** элементом внутри элемента `block`. Первыми являются элементы `Link`, вторыми являются элементы `text`

Comment: У меня везде одинаковая картинка лягушка, а картинки  должны быть разными

Comment: Если вы хотите, чтобы фон менялся в зависимости от позиции `block`, то значит и добавлять `nth-child` нужно именно к `block`: `.block:nth-child(1) .Background-img {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если бы вы хотя бы бегло ознакомились с документацией - [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), то обратили бы внимание на описание данного псевдо-класса:

> CSS псевдокласс `:nth-child()` находит один или более элементов, основываясь на их позиции среди группы соседних элементов.

Визуально:

```html
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>              <!-- *:nth-child(1) -->
<p class ="text"> 3 </p>                   <!-- *:nth-child(2) -->
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>  <!-- *:nth-child(3) -->
```

Но в вашем случае, при использованием `.Background-img:nth-child(1)` можно расценивать как условие `любой элемент с классом (*) && порядковым номером (*)`, поэтому в вашем случае игнорируется `:nth-child()` с параметром 1 и 2, но не 3, т.к. он совпадает по условию.

По вашей задача требуется в каждом `.parent .block` найти `.Background-img` и ему выставить `background-image` в зависимости от порядкового номера **родителя**, т.е. элемента `.block`, по этому правильной записью будет являться:

```css
.parent .block:nth-child(1) .Background-img {}
.parent .block:nth-child(2) .Background-img {}
.parent .block:nth-child(3) .Background-img {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Твоя ошибка в том, что здесь лучше использовать nth-of-type.
И для надежности я бы это все обернула в отдельный div, чтобы не считались какие-то другие элементы.

Ну и лучше не использовать классы с заглавными буквами. Сложно следить где с заглавной, где с маленькой. Опечатаешься, вылезет баг и будет сложно искать.

```css
.block{
width:200px;
border:1px solid black;
height:150px;
margin:20px;
display:inline-block;
}
.text{
color:red;
font-size:20px;
position:absolute;
}
.Background-img{
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-size: cover;
margin:0;
padding: 0;
}

.block:nth-of-type(1) .Background-img {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/68rFc89/1560329641-2.jpg');
}

.block:nth-of-type(2) .Background-img {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/wJFNhpN/multfilm-lyagushka-32117.jpg');
}

.block:nth-of-type(3) .Background-img {
background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/5jMv9vd/detail-2b7c4f333c37580ee03adaa3bc47c4da.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class ="block">
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>
<p class ="text"> 1 </p>
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>
</div>

<div class ="block">
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>
<p class ="text"> 2 </p>
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>
</div>

<div class ="block">
<a class ="Link" href=""></a>
<p class ="text"> 3 </p>
<figure class="Background-img"> </figure>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ошибка заключается не в том, что используется `:nth-child()` или `:nth-of-type()`, а в отсутствие понимая принципа работы данных псевдо-классов.

Comment: ну и? задача выше решена, остальное придет со временем.